# Error 13 Permission denied when trying to write on unrelated folder

Tags: python, windows

I dont have much experience in python, so it might be a stupid question.

Im trying to write to a file in my script, if I run the script from his folder, it works, however if I run it from another folder, I have an error 13 persmission denied

i.e. in cmd :

```
cd C:\Users\user010\Perforce\Build\LS3\
py Build_jenkins.py
```

works but

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\LC3.3 Test\Qt\main
py C:\Users\user010\Perforce\Build\LS3\Build_jenkins.py
```

doesnt work. I have tried moving the script and the file to a public folder, same error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Build\LS3\Build_jenkins.py", line 159, in <module>
    Variables.Sauvegarder()
  File "C:/Users/Public/Documents/Build/LS3/../Common\Variables.py", line 87, in Sauvegarder
    gArbre.write( NOM_FICHIER )
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 761, in write
    with _get_writer(file_or_filename, encoding) as write:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 798, in _get_writer
    errors="xmlcharrefreplace")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Variables.xml'
```

The code is  `Variables.Sauvegarder()` in my main file and in Variables :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
gArbre = ET.parse( "Variables.xml" )
def Sauvegarder():
    gArbre.write( "Variables.xml")
```

Edit : important detail I forgot to mention, the file im writing to is located in the script folder (C:/Users/Public/Documents/Build/LS3/../Common\Variables.xml)

Comment: A standard user doesn't have write access to folders in `C:\Program Files (x86)` and shouldn't be writing data files there.

Comment: If you look at [windows folder permissions](http://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line) from the 2 locations you are executing the `py` command from you should see why this won't work.

Comment: what is `NOM_FICHIER`, is it a folder?

Comment: @eryksun the file im writing to is not in program files, its right next to the python script, i.e in my user folder, or in the second test, in public folder

Comment: @HaifengZhang NOM_FICHIER is Variables.xml forgot to replace this one, i edit my post

Comment: In the statement `gArbre = ET.parse( "Variables.xml" )`, the name "Variables.xml" is qualified relative to the working directory, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\LC3.3 Test\Qt\main". I have no idea why you'd be running with that working directory or why there's already a "Variables.xml" file there. Unless the permissions on the directory were manually changed, they're inherited from "C:\Program Files (x86)", which does not allow standard users to make changes, and no program or user should be creating data files there.

Comment: @eryksun that was it, I thought it would use a relative path from the module im using since im importing it in my script, but its using the path from where im calling. Newbie mistake, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure about Windows computers (for a mac or other linux-based system you'd use sudo), but I would recommend trying to run the command as an administrator (use the runas command plus the name of an account with admin priveledges.) That should hopefully fix the error you're getting.

Comment: you can post it as a comment

Comment: @HaifengZhang What's the difference? (I don't mean this in a mean way, I'm just genuinely curious; I just joined today so I still don't know all of the etiquette  rules) Thanks.